# php check expired dates and delete after 1 day

Tags: php

My objective is...

If the date is expired... the script gives 1 more day to the user, then if not subscribed, the user data is deleted.

How can I do it?... I tried INTERVAL 1 DAY, but... I don't know if works...

```
// Check Expire Dates and Delete Expired 1 day after.
  $now = date('Y-m-d');

  if ($row['expire_admin'] > $now)
  {
    echo " <a href='#' id='profileGhost'> ". $row['expire_admin'] . "</a>";
  }
  else
  {
    echo " <a href='#' id='profileGhost'>Expired.</a>";
    $queryExpire = "DELETE FROM public_vips WHERE expire_admin(expire_admin, INTERVAL 1 day), steamid='$steamID'";
    $expiredQ = mysqli_query($db, $queryExpire);
  }
```

Comment: what's the format of `$row['expire_admin']` ?

Comment: Don't you want $row['expire_admin'] < $now, since expire_admin should be in the past (less than now) in order to be deleted?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
// Check Expire Dates and Delete Expired 1 day after.
$now = new DateTime();
$tomorrow = new DateTime();
$tomorrow->add( new DateInterval( 'P1D' ) );
$expiration_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('Y-m-d', $row['expire_admin'] );

if ( $expiration_date->format('u') > $now->format('u') )
{
    if( $expiration_date->format('u') < $tomorrow->format('u') )
        echo " <a href='#' id='profileGhost'> ". $row['expire_admin'] . "</a>";
    }
    else
    {
        echo " <a href='#' id='profileGhost'>Expired.</a>";

        // I suppose that steamID is the unique id of the row you are currently check
        $queryExpire = "DELETE FROM public_vips WHERE steamid='$steamID'";
        $expiredQ = mysqli_query($db, $queryExpire);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your SQL should probably be

```
DELETE FROM public_vips 
WHERE expire_admin(expire_admin, INTERVAL 1 day)
    AND steamid='$steamID'
```